# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError Exception: element not visible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, capybara

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError Exception: element
>   not visible

I am trying to access an element in my cucumber with headless chrome.and in my `.env.rb` I have  this,

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
    args: %w[headless disable-gpu no-sandbox]
  )
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
end
Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```

and in my set definition, I have

```
Then(/^I should see the "([^"]*)" link on the page$/) do |link_text|
  expect(page).to have_css("a", text:  link_text)
end
```

but the element is not visible on my test if I run it without headless chrome mode the element is visible. Can anyoin point me on the right direction? Thanks in advance

Comment: I would start from maximizing 'headless' window

Comment: You shouldn't be getting that error from Capybara (at least not from the line of code with `have_css`).  The error you would get from that line should have a message like `expected to find visible css "a" with text "not there" but there were no matches. Also found ...`.  Are you running a really old version of Capybara?  Add the full error message you're getting to your question.  Also you might want to use `have_link(link_text)` in the future rather than 'have_css("a", text: ...)` just for readability sake.

Comment: One other thing to try is to use `save_and_open_screenshot` before the line you're getting the failure at to see what the page actually looks like at that point in time.

Comment: One final question, when you say "without headless chrome", do you mean still using chrome just not headless, or do you mean using the rack_test driver?  If you mean rack_test,  it doesn't process most CSS so the accuracy of visibility when using it is likely to be questionable.